# Libgdx Quiz Storage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a quiz in Libgdx and am trying to find the best solution for storing the questions and answers since they don't support sqlite.

I've never coded in json before so trying that out was pretty hard. I also tried it out with the shared preferences which worked good with a few questions but unsure on say 500 questions.

I also tried XML storage which worked out too.

My question is for an app that will have say 500 questions/answers what would be the best choice here?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again? If XML works for you, what's the problem? JSON would probably be easier to use, easier to maintain and a more efficient way of storage, but it probably doesn't matter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server :D

Imagine setting up a server based quiz. You could change the questions directly in the database without forcing users to download new version each time?

But all in all, like above said. If it works, what's stopping you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i thought about a server side way of doing it such as mysql but i thought using something like that in apps would cause problems either with efficiency or if the user doesn't have a data plan etc .

Comment: Or doesn't have an internet connection... which might be the case with any user any time

Comment: If they had internet they could receive updates, if they don't they keep the built in questions or any updates they received while they had internet, could that work?

Comment: Exactly. Just because you run a server doesn't mean you are back-end locked. If a successful request has been aquired, store the questions in preferences. If we can't contact server, use the local questions. If not, overwrite em :)

Comment: Sounds good thank you, i just assumed using things like mysql or online databases for mobile apps was not good practise or such.

Comment: It's a very nice thing to carry with you. Opens up a whole new dimension of possibilities! Although it might not be an easy task to master it's definitely useful :)